# How to configure Confluent hdfs sink connector for remote machine?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How to configure hdfs sink connector from ' A '  Kafka machine to 'B' Hadoop machine how to I do that ? Any good example?

Answer (score 0):

Run Kafka Connect on machine 'C' (set the `bootstrap.servers` to point to machine 'A'). 
Then create a connector using [HDFS Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#configuration) with `hdfs.url` to point to machine 'B', streaming data from Kafka topic on machine 'A'.

Answer (score 0):

```
connect-standalone etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties etc/kafka-connect-hdfs/quickstart-hdfs.properties
```

Assuming that Kafka is running on machine A.Only changes you have to make in quickstart-hdfs.properties

```
hdfs.url=hdfs://url.of.machine.B:9000
```

Make sure that you are able to make the connection from A to B properly.